# SQL 2008: Insert multiple rows based on specific criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to clone user permissions. The permissions are driven from a table with only 2 columns, userid and groupid. Both are foreign keys.

Is it possible to insert multiple rows based on criteria? Let's say:

> USERID     GROUPID
>
> 1          A
>
> 1          B
>
> 1          C
>
> 1          D

I would like to insert rows to give USER 2 the same GROUPS as USER 1.

Does this get me close?

```
INSERT INTO ide_usergroup_assoc (userid, groupid)
VALUES ('USERID I PROVIDE', (SELECT ide_usergroup_assoc.groupid from ide_usergroup_assoc WHERE ide_usergroup_assoc.userid = 'USERID TO BE CLONED'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
insert into ide_usergroup_assoc (userid, groupid)
select 2, groupid
from ide_usergroup_assoc 
where userid = 1
```

Comment: Well that was entirely too easy. Thank you.